# How can I create a hidden Administrator account in a public computer?

Tags: account-security, windows-7

After my journey for finding a way to [create a truly private user account in a public computer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/206157/is-it-possible-to-create-a-truly-private-user-account-in-a-public-computer) (the setup I'm trying to do this on is detailed in this other question) ended in an epic fail I'm now taking a different approach to the subject: creating a regular admin account (I accept suggestions that require the super administrator account, but I'd like to avoid it) but make finding it extremely hard if you don't know what you're doing/looking after. Interactive logon is enabled on the college computer, so it helps I guess.

I need the account to not show up on the:

- Users folder.
- logon screen (we got interactive logon so this is easy).
- net user command/any user listing.

These characteristics are the most necessary ones since without them it's possible to come across the account by accident. If you have a suggestion that only fits 1 or 2 of them please don't hesitate to comment, anything helps! Additional coverage/hiding and boring maneuvers like disabling/enabling the account every time I want to use it are welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can hide a user from the net user command. I may be wrong on that point, but if I remember correctly net user use the SAM file that manage all users accounts.

But you can hide a user from the user folder and the logon screen with the cmd command :

`reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\Userlist" /v <ACCOUNTNAME> /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`

(Replace the `<ACCOUNTNAME>` with your account name)

Comment: This is great! Yea I was pretty sure hiding from the net user command wouldn't be possible but it wouldn't hurt to ask. Thanks a lot for your help